# How to output file in function in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to output "a" to the file in the function, how do I do it? The following gives me error.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

void outputfile(const char* file);

int main() 
{
    int a = 1;
    ofstream cc;
    cc.open("123.txt");
    if (cc.fail()) 
    {
        cout << "\nError in file opening" << endl;
        return(1);
    }
    outputfile("123.txt");
    cc.close();
    return 0;
}

void outputfile(const char* file)
{
    // I want to output a to the file, how can I do it? The following gives me error.
    file << a;
}
```

The problem is solved, thanks for answering the question.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see couple of issues that need to be addressed.

1. You can either pass the name of the file to `outputfile` or the `ofstream`. If you pass the name of the file to `outputfile`, the file needs to be opened in `outputfile`, not in `main`.

   There are pros and cons to the two approaches. If the name of the file is passed to `outputfile`, `main` becomes very simple. However, if the `ofstream` object needs to be used to make other function calls, it will be better to pass an `ofstream` as the argument to `outputfile`.

   If a `ofstream` is passed to `outputfile`, `outputfile` becomes very simple. However, if the `ofstream` is not going to be used by `main` for anything else, it is better to leave the details of what mechanism used by `outputfile` to write the data out. `outputfile` can even resort to `FILE*` and `fprintf` without affecting `main`.
2. `a` needs to be made available to `outputfile`. It can be made a global variable or be passed to `outputfile`. It is better to avoid global data. Hence, prefer to pass it as an argument.

**Solution 1**

Pass an `ofstream` to `outputfile`, in addition to `a`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

void outputfile(std::ofstream& file, int a);

int main() 
{
   int a = 1;
   ofstream cc;
   cc.open("123.txt");
   if (cc.fail()) 
   {
      cout << "\nError in file opening" << endl;
      return(1);
   }
   outputfile(cc, a);

   // No need. The file will be closed when the function returns.
   // cc.close();

   return 0;
}

void outputfile(std::ofstream& file, int a)
{
    file << a;
}
```

**Solution 2**

The details of opening and closing the file is left to `outputfile`. Here, `outputfile` uses `ofstream`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

void outputfile(char const* file, int a);

int main() 
{
   int a = 1;
   outputfile("123.txt", a);

   return 0;
}

void outputfile(char const* file, int a)
{
   ofstream cc(file);
   if (cc.fail()) 
   {
      cout << "\nError in file opening" << endl;
      return;
   }
   cc << a;
}
```

**Solution 3**

The details of opening and closing the file is left to `outputfile`. Here, `outputfile` uses `FILE*`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

void outputfile(char const* file, int a);

int main() 
{
   int a = 1;
   outputfile("123.txt", a);

   return 0;
}

void outputfile(char const* file, int a)
{
   FILE* fp = fopen(file, "w");
   if ( fp == NULL )
   {
      cout << "\nError in file opening" << endl;
      return;
   }
   fprintf(fp, "%d", a);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, you have declared `a` in `main()`. Either you have to pass it as parameter or you have to take it global. I took global in the code below.

Then what do you do passing `const char*`? You have to write in file, so send the stream instead like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
 void outputfile(ofstream &file);  int a=1;
 int main() {

  ofstream cc;
  cc.open("123.txt");
  if (cc.fail()) {
    cout <<"\nError in file opening" << endl;
    return(1);
  }
  outputfile(cc);
  cc.close();
  return 0;
}
void outputfile(ofstream &file)
{
  // I want to output a to the file, how do I do it? The following gives me error.
  file << a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` isn't in scope.  Either declare it outside of `main()` in global space, or pass it into `outputfile`, something like:

```
void outputfile(ofstream &file file, int a) {
    file << a;
}
```

Comment: In his first block of code, his `outputfile` function takes a char* path, not an ofstream.  So there's a lot more wrong with his code than just that.